# How do I move a hard drive with Windows 7 from one machine to another?

Tags: windows-7

Back in the XP days there was the sysprep tool but google returns hits only in context with XP and earlier operating systems.

Comment: Make sure it is similar hardware otherwise you could get errors.

Comment: it can be done with Vista too, just install the generic Microsoft Standard IDE Controller before moving the drive to another machine. of course this does require re-activation when done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **sysprep.exe** in the **%WINDIR%\system32\sysprep** folder. See [Sysprep Technical Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744263(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, the key here is that this 'Applies to: Windows 7'. I have used it in the past but all the google hits for it returned references to XP and 98SE.